# Sequencing/grouping broken sequnce numbers in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have the data like,

```
Term_order, name
1,Summer
2,Fall
3,Spring
4,Fall
5,Fall
6,Spring
7,Summer
8,Spring
```

I am trying to calculate the Year column. A year can start with summer and can end with spring. Su, Fa, Sp is the order. That said, the result should be,

```
Term_order, name, year
1, Summer, 1
2, Fall, 1
3, Spring, 1
4, Fall, 2 (note that year 2 does not have Su, but it has ordered it and fall is the first term.so it marked it as year 2)
5, Fall, 3
6, Spring, 3
7, Summer, 4
8, Spring, 4
```

I tried converting the summer, fall, spring to number like 1,2,3 and tried creating rank based on term_num and term_nm. I know it does not work as there is no grouping here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a classic [*Gaps-and-Islands* problem](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/introduction-to-gaps-and-islands-analysis/).**

We can start by assigning the seasons a number in order: 1 for Summer, 2 for Fall, etc.

Then we can use `LAG` to check if the previous row is the same or later season, in which case we must have gone over to a new year, and mark those rows.

Then we simply do a running count of those marked rows, adding 1 to begin the count at 1.

```sql
WITH NumberedSeason AS (
    SELECT *,
      Season = CASE name
        WHEN 'Summer' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Fall' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Winter' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
        END
    FROM Term
),
Gaps AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsNewYear = CASE WHEN LAG(Season) OVER (ORDER BY Term_order) >= Season THEN 1 END
    FROM NumberedSeason
)
SELECT
  Term_order,
  name,
  Year = COUNT(IsNewYear) OVER (ORDER BY Term_order ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + 1
FROM Gaps;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/FiM1Acwg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will work on it. I also looked at an other solution of row_num-1 using a self join on with clause. But tge lag function looks straight forward

Comment: It worked. I actually have other colums to group by like the term number and name changes by school and program. Included them under partition by to set the bound. The logic of setting '1' and summing up with the current row to find the iteration is awesome. Thanks again.